# Problem with openssl functions for certificate authority

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa, x509certificate, x509

I want to write a program for a client and server that they need to connect with certificate authority before connection.
I'm using openssl for the algorithms.
When I run the client in terminal I get these errors:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_EVP_PKEY_assign", referenced from:
  generate_key() in Alice-c8763f.o
      "_EVP_PKEY_free", referenced from:
  generate_key() in Alice-c8763f.o
      "_EVP_PKEY_new", referenced from:
  generate_key() in Alice-c8763f.o
      "_RSA_generate_key", referenced from:
  generate_key() in Alice-c8763f.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Actually the client first generates RSA key and send to CA for x509 certificate.
in CA code also I get these errors:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_ASN1_INTEGER_set", referenced from:
  generate_x509(evp_pkey_st*) in CA-ceff6a.o
      "_EVP_PKEY_free", referenced from:
  routine1(void*) in CA-ceff6a.o
      "_EVP_sha1", referenced from:
  generate_x509(evp_pkey_st*) in CA-ceff6a.o
      "_PEM_write_PrivateKey", referenced from:
  write_to_disk(evp_pkey_st*, x509_st*) in CA-ceff6a.o
      "_PEM_write_X509", referenced from:
  write_to_disk(evp_pkey_st*, x509_st*) in CA-ceff6a.o
      "_X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt", referenced from:
  generate_x509(evp_pkey_st*) in CA-ceff6a.o
      "_X509_free", referenced from:
  generate_x509(evp_pkey_st*) in CA-ceff6a.o
  routine1(void*) in CA-ceff6a.o
      "_X509_get_serialNumber", referenced from:
  generate_x509(evp_pkey_st*) in CA-ceff6a.o
      "_X509_get_subject_name", referenced from:
  generate_x509(evp_pkey_st*) in CA-ceff6a.o
      "_X509_gmtime_adj", referenced from:
  generate_x509(evp_pkey_st*) in CA-ceff6a.o
      "_X509_new", referenced from:
  generate_x509(evp_pkey_st*) in CA-ceff6a.o
      "_X509_set_issuer_name", referenced from:
  generate_x509(evp_pkey_st*) in CA-ceff6a.o
      "_X509_set_pubkey", referenced from:
  generate_x509(evp_pkey_st*) in CA-ceff6a.o
      "_X509_sign", referenced from:
  generate_x509(evp_pkey_st*) in CA-ceff6a.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

can Anyone help me solve this problem?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

How are you compiling and linking your program? Looks like you are missing the `crypto` library. According to `pkg-config --libs libcrypto`, you just need to pass `-lcrypto -lz` to the linker.